# In TFS 2018, is it possible to set global notifications across an entire collection?

Tags: tfs

We currently have 30+ projects within a collection in our TFS server and I would like to send a notification to a team email address when a build fails in any of the projects in the collection.

How would I achieve this? Currently, the only way I see how to configure this is to manually create a notification for each project within the collection. It would be tedious to do this for any new notifications that we deem important enough to send to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Directly create collection level notifications for **all** teams/groups/users is not supported for now.

However if your just want to set a notification for a specific Group/User across an entire collection, then you can try below steps:

1. Create a Group -> Add memebers to the group
2. Navigate to **Notifications** hub in collection level
3. Switch to **Subscribers** tab -> **Search Users and Groups** ->
   Select the specific user/group
4. **New Subscription** -> **Build** -> **A build fails** -> **Next** ->  Deliver to : **Individual xxx members** or **Team email address** ->
   Filter: **Any team project**

[image]

Comment: @shaboinkin Have you resolved the issue by above answer? any update?